# Gibbs free energy and chemical potential

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, chemical-potential

[image]

I would like to know when is the summation term zero. Can it be non-zero in a closed system that does additional work (so PV work + chemical work). I would really appreciate an explanation about this term.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a particle to a system, then the internal energy will change by an amount which we call the chemical potential $\mu$. Thus we add a term $\mu dN$ to the expression
$$dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN$$

> I would like to know when is the summation term zero.

The summation term would  be zero if
$$\sum_i \mu_idN_i=0\Rightarrow dN_i=0 \ \ \ \ \ \text{closed system}$$

> Can it be non-zero in a closed system?

Yes! In chemical reactions such as
$$A\rightarrow B$$
$$dG=\mu_AdN_A+\mu_BdN_B$$
However, since an increase in B is always accompanied by a corresponding decrease in $A$, we have that
$$dG=(\mu_B-\mu_A)dN_B\not=0$$
In equilibrium at constant temperature and pressure, we have that the Gibbs function is minimized
$$dG=0\Rightarrow \mu_A=\mu_B$$

---

In a similar way, the closed system might be composed of different phases of different substances. In general $dG\not=0$ unless there is an equilibrium between different phases.

Comment: Thank you! But then I don't understand something. If dG is defined as  dG= ∑, then all the processes that take place in a closed system are reversible since dG = 0 ?

Comment: The expression you have written for $dG$ required constant pressure and temperature.

Comment: If there is a chemical reaction in a closed system, the summation term is not zero (unless the reaction is at equilibrium).

Comment: I'm so confused :(. Then in a closed system, if there occurs a chemical reaction at cte T and cte P, dG is different from zero ?

Comment: @GemaCabero Please find the edit.